# Google Map google-play-services-lib Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I was trying to run a google map application, but when I include google-play-services-lib first, it shows like this

[image]

but after that when I recheck it shows

[image]

because of this my application is crashing could anyone possibly tell me what could be the scenario?

Comment: Try to copy the Google Play services lib into your workspace and reference it from there, or when importing it check the "Copy to current workspace" checkbox in import new project wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your Google Play Services library and your project folder in same drive and then import library from that drive after that clean your project.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your project and google play library in same folder. Remove that red color error library from android properties and add it again with new drive. May be it will work.